# session variable is not displayed in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I want to add a session variable in my controller and access it on my view, the controller look like this..

```
        public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = Repository.GetChartData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30), DateTime.Now);
        Session["TheDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But in my view nothing is displayed when using this @Session["TheDate"], what can I do to make this work?

Comment: are you calling `GetData()` using ajax?

Comment: Yes in a javascript function in order to populate a chart.

Comment: can you share the ajax Code? (javascript function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that you are accessing JSON data by AJAX. You are not rendering a View on the server.

Accessing the session with razor syntax `@Session["TheDate"]` only works on the server side (during rendering of the View). You can not access this from the client side (e.g. in a `success` callback of an AJAX request).

Maybe you can transport the date to the client as part of the JSON object?

```
{
    "TheDate": "2017-02-15",
    "Data": data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the JSON response in my javascript code instead in order to access the JSON response. But I still think its weird that session variables didnt work...